# Why ng serve is not working if project cli is v9 and global cli is v11?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed cli v9 in an Angular project, amd the global version of cli is 11.

When I tried "ng serve", I have the following error:

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions
> ^9.0.0-next || >=9.0.0 <10.0.0, but Angular version 11.2.9 was found
> instead

Answer (score 0):

To run project, try  running npm scripts instead of global ng serve, npm command will use local version / cli from respective project node_modules folder.

Run start script defined in package json.

1. **npm run start**